# Upgrading PostgreSQL 9.2.15 to 16.1 - Incremental Version Updates?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm dealing with an older PostgreSQL database running on version 9.2.15. I aim to upgrade it to the latest version 16.1 without losing data if possible. Should I perform incremental updates to major versions in between ?
If so, which specific versions should I consider in the process ?

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How large is the database? There's a huge difference for available options on 10MiB, 10GiB or 10TiB databases.

Comment: You can directly upgrade from 9.2 to v16.

Comment: The database is pretty large, it has about 17GiB

Comment: I would upgrade directly from 9 to 16; but test your application throughfully, there are some differences which could cause issues between both versions.

Comment: That's small enough to fit on a £5 USB stick. Install postgresql 16 (assuming your system easily supports two simultaneous installations), and use it's pg_dump and pg_restore to move your database(s) over. Test things out before deleting the v9.

Comment: There are a lot of differences between 9.2 and 16, for instance plpython2u is no longer supported. I would go through the release notes for the first release of each version to see what the breaking changes are starting with [9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/release-9-3.html).